# Validation and conversion in JSF

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I'm reading the following [article](http://balusc.blogspot.ru/2006/09/debug-jsf-lifecycle.html) about JSF lifecycle and was a little confused about the the process validation phase.

If we have both conversion and validation needed to be proceed fot the same component, is it realiable that conversion always happens before validation?

Comment: @BalusC Almost, You said in the answer that we first converting the value and then perform all validations delcared for the component. Is that true for any component, not only for `UIInput`? Or it depends on the component?

Comment: Technically, only [`EditableValueHolder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/EditableValueHolder.html) instances support both conversion and validation, and in standard JSF the only implementations are all `UIInput` classes. So, yes it's after all only for `UIInput`. Other components don't support validators anyway.

Comment: @BalusC Indeed, yes. I just tried to think more generally and lost the fact the we need to validate user input for only components that allow user to input something (i.e.`UIInput`).